# How to avoid double quoted string , site URL and email address from tokenization

Tags: python, nlp

How we I stop `word_tokenize` from splittings strings like `"pass_word"`, `"https://www.gmail.com"` and `"tempemail@mail.com"`? The quotes should prevent it, but they don't.

I have tried with different regex options.

```py
from nltk import word_tokenize

s = 'open "https://www.gmail.com" url. Enter "tempemail@mail.com" in email. Enter "pass_word" in password.'
for phrase in re.findall('"([^"]*)"', s):
    s = s.replace('"{}"'.format(phrase), phrase.replace(' ', '*'))
tokens = word_tokenize(s)
print(tokens)
```

Actual response:

```
['open', 'https', ':', '//www.gmail.com', 'url', '.', 'Enter', 
 'tempemail', '@', 'mail.com', 'in', 'email', '.', 'Enter', 
 'pass_word', 'in', 'password', '.']
```

Expected response:

```
['open', 'https://www.gmail.com', 'url', '.', 'Enter', 
 'tempemail@mail.com', 'in', 'email', '.', 'Enter', 
 'pass_word', 'in', 'password', '.']
```

Comment: You can try TweetTokenizer, described here: https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html . Otherwise you'll have to edit the tokenizer code to tweak tokenization rules yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:
First, tokenize the text into sentences. If a sentence contains a special character, tokenize it with the `str.split()` function, otherwise use `word_tokenize`.

```
tokens=[]
for sent in sent_tokenize(s):
if re.match(r'^\w+$', s):
    for token in word_tokenize(sent):
        tokens.append(token)
else:
    for token in sent.split():
        tokens.append(token)
print(tokens)
```

Outputs:

```
['open', '"https://www.gmail.com"', 'url.', 'Enter', '"tempemail@mail.com"', 'in', 'email.', 'Enter', '"pass_word"', 'in', 'password.']
```

**EDIT**
You can tokenize periods by further splitting the string using period.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It helped me to resolve my issue.(code after modifications)
s = 'open "https://www.gmail.com" url. Enter "tempemail@mail.com" in email. Enter "pass word" "sample_pass" in password.'
tokens = []
for sent in sent_tokenize(s):
    for phrase in re.findall('"([^"]*)"', sent):
        sent = sent.replace('"{}"'.format(
            phrase), phrase.replace(' ', '*spc*'))

    for token in sent.split():
        if str(token).endswith('.'):
            token = token[:-1]
        tokens.append(token)
print(tokens)